# Can I use “respectively” when two lists are in the different sentences?

Tags: word-usage

I paid one dollar for candy, and I paid two dollars for chocolate.

Can I say like this?

“I paid one dollar(1) and two dollars(2). I bought candy(1) and chocolate(2) respectively.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two short statements can/should be joined:

> I bought a family pack of candy and chocolate. I paid only two dollars and one dollar respectively.
> I **bought** [a family pack of] candy and chocolate **for** [only] one dollar and two dollars respectively.

> I **paid** $1 and $2 **for** [a family pack of] candy and chocolate respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but why would you?  It is just about the most confusing way you express yourself.

So don't do that.

Instead how about:

> I paid one dollar for candy, and I paid two dollars for chocolate.

Answer (score 0):

The two sentences are clearly and directly related to each other, so yes, you can.

In non-written contexts, you can also refer to an ordered list by gesturing at a set of things, so it can be entirely non-verbal.  The only requirement is that the listener or reader must be able to determine what ordered list you are referring to with the "respectively".